# Using MongoDB on RaspberryPi via SSH connection in VS Code

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, ssh, permissions, raspberry-pi

I installed MongoDB via the official documentation on my Raspberry Pi, which I access using SSH remote connection in VSCode from my actual Desktop.

The installation looked all good, but I can't get the service to start using

`sudo systemctl start mongod`.

This is what I get from

`sudo systemctl status mongod`

```
mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Wed 2021-08-04 12:42:10 UTC; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 4442 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 4442 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Aug 04 12:42:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Aug 04 12:42:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Aug 04 12:42:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

I tried changing all kinds of permissions and unfortunately no log files are created in the process. My last idea would be that I have to change the **ipbind** setting in order to make it work, but I already tried commenting it out in the config file, as well as replacing it with 0.0.0.0

At this point I don't know how to progress, so any help would be welcome!

Comment: what if you start mongodb from a direct screen/keyboard connection

Comment: Did you check the mongodb log file?

Comment: I reinstalled it again - still no log file in ```/var/log/mongodb```

Comment: the permissions for the log folder are:

```ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/log/mongodb$ ls -la .```
```total 8```
```drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Aug  5 07:02 .```
```drwxrwxr-x 12 root    syslog  4096 Aug  5 07:02 ..```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the latest version (5.0) is not compatible with Raspberry Pi 4.

I got it to work by installing MongoDB 4.4.8 using the command

`sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=4.4.8 mongodb-org-server=4.4.8 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.8 mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.8 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.8`

I also then locked the versions using

`echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections && echo "mongodb-org-server hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections && echo "mongodb-org-shell hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections && echo "mongodb-org-mongos hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections && echo "mongodb-org-tools hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`

to prevent apt-get from updating.

More information: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/core-dump-on-mongodb-5-0-on-rpi-4/115291/14